# Detecting questions using Parsey's Dependency parser

Tags: stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

Is there any way to detect if there exists a question in the sentence using Parsey's dependency parser alone? The regular stanford parser provides a tag of SBARQ or SQ for questions. Is there anything similar for parsey's dependency parser?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions  Bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you refer to Google's Parsey McParseface. This parser is said to be compliant to the annotation guidelines from Universal Dependencies (http://universaldependencies.org/), so I believe you should find answer there.

At least in case of English, no question-marking item is documented. I've searched “English (UDv2.0)” corpus at http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/dep_search/ and there is no trace of this information (aside from the interrogative pronoun, which may be ambiguous), for instance:

```
1   Who who PRON    WP  PronType=Int    2   nsubj   _   _
2   cares   care    VERB    VBZ Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   0   root    _   SpaceAfter=No
3   ??????  ??????  PUNCT   .   _   2   punct   _   _
```

Dependency parsing is more focused on the surface form and probably whether the sentence is a question or not is deemed here part of semantics, so not decided on this level. The Stanford constituency parser outputs something which resembles the oldish Chomskian X-bar theory, where things look quite differently.